# Return não funcionando na function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho esta função, porém o retorno não funciona nela, eu não quero que ele saia dela, enquanto não estiver conforme a função:

```
if ($('#FreteComprador').prop("checked") == true) {
        var id = $("#idtransportador").val();
        var frete = $("#Frete").val();
        if (id == "") {
            alert("Preencha o campo transportador corretamente.");
            return;
        } else {
            var url = "/PedidoFornecedor/VerificaCNPJ";
            $.ajax({
                url: url
                , data: { id: id }
                , type: "POST"
                , datatype: "html"
                , success: function (data) {
                    if (data.resultado == true && frete == "0,00") {
                            alert("É obrigatório preencher o valor do frete.");
                            return;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Como posso fazer? Nos outros ifs, quando coloco `return` funciona, neste ele sai da função.

Comment: Eu acredito que tem um problema no seu código que é o seguinte, você está disparando o ajax antes de validar o frete. Não sei da sua regra de negocio mas isso me esta um pouco estranho, no success da requisilçao ajax que está testando se foi preenchido?

Comment: É porque ele tem que verificar se o frete for pelo próprio fornecedor ele não precisa ser preenchido, por isto, esta função, se no sucess ele retornar true, ele tem que ser obrigatório preencher o frete.

Comment: Aonde que está o problema no código?

Comment: Ele sai no return, ele devia parar ai e não entrar no próximo if.

Comment: experimente colocar return false;

Comment: Não funcionou, ele entra no próximo if, e depois volta neste.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84703/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-marianac-costa).

Comment: A função `$.ajax` por padrão funciona de forma **async**, ou seja, ela não vai retornar o resultado na proxima linha de código, para isso você deve usar a callback `success:function(){}` para continuar suas checagens, lembrando que também existe uma callback para o caso de error no request. [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fomos conversando e testando, está faltando colocar um `async: false` como parametro do seu ajax